# JSON: get json array if it has specific value

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object with data:

```
{
  "ROOT": {
    "CATEGORY_AREA_LIST": {
      "CATEGORY_AREA": [{
        "@attributes": {
          "CATEGORY_AREA_NAME": "General"
        },
        "CATEGORY_TYPE": [{
          "@attributes": {
            "CATEGORY_TYPE_NAME": "MOC"
          },
          "CATEGORY_LOCATION": [{
            "@attributes": {
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Location1",
              "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "1"
            }
          }, {
            "@attributes": {
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Location2",
              "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "2"
            }
          }, {
            "@attributes": {
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Location3",
              "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "3"
            }
          }, {
            "@attributes": {
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Location4",
              "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "4"
            }
          }]
        }, {
          "@attributes": {
            "CATEGORY_TYPE_NAME": "LPG"
          },
          "CATEGORY_LOCATION": [{
            "@attributes": {
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Location20",
              "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "11"
            }
          }, {
            "@attributes": {
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Location22",
              "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "21"
            }
          }, {
            "@attributes": {
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Location222",
              "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "13"
            }
          }, {
            "@attributes": {
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Location2222",
              "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "41"
            }
          }]
        }]
      }, {
        "@attributes": {
          "CATEGORY_AREA_NAME": "Restricted"
        },
        "CATEGORY_TYPE": [{
          "@attributes": {
            "CATEGORY_TYPE_NAME": "DND"
          },
          "CATEGORY_LOCATION": [{
            "@attributes": {
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "L1",
              "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "11"
            }
          }, {
            "@attributes": {
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "L2",
              "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "22"
            }
          }, {
            "@attributes": {
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "L3",
              "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "33"
            }
          }, {
            "@attributes": {
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "L4",
              "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "44"
            }
          }]
        }, {
          "@attributes": {
            "CATEGORY_TYPE_NAME": "MNN"
          },
          "CATEGORY_LOCATION": [{
            "@attributes": {
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Loc33",
              "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "8"
            }
          }, {
            "@attributes": {
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Loc333",
              "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "7"
            }
          }, {
            "@attributes": {
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Loc33333",
              "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "6"
            }
          }, {
            "@attributes": {
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Loc333333",
              "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "5"
            }
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I need to fetch `CATEGORY_AREA` object which has an attribute `CATEGORY_AREA_NAME = "General"`.

I tried with `filter`/`find` function, but not getting desired result.

Solution:

> var jsArray = JSON.parse(jsonObj); var result =
>   jsArray["ROOT"]["CATEGORY_AREA_LIST"]["CATEGORY_AREA"].find(current=>{
>         if(current["@attributes"]["CATEGORY_AREA_NAME"] == "General")
>             return current;     });

Comment: *"I tried with filter/find function, but not getting desired result."* Show us that.

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow my method:

```js
var obj = {
  "ROOT": {
    "CATEGORY_AREA_LIST": {
      "CATEGORY_AREA": [
        {
          "@attributes": {
            "CATEGORY_AREA_NAME": "General"
          },
          "CATEGORY_TYPE": [
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "CATEGORY_TYPE_NAME": "MOC"
              },
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION": [
                {
                  "@attributes": {
                    "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Location1",
                    "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "1"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "@attributes": {
                    "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Location2",
                    "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "2"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "@attributes": {
                    "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Location3",
                    "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "3"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "@attributes": {
                    "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Location4",
                    "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "4"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "CATEGORY_TYPE_NAME": "LPG"
              },
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION": [
                {
                  "@attributes": {
                    "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Location20",
                    "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "11"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "@attributes": {
                    "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Location22",
                    "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "21"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "@attributes": {
                    "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Location222",
                    "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "13"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "@attributes": {
                    "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Location2222",
                    "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "41"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "@attributes": {
            "CATEGORY_AREA_NAME": "Restricted"
          },
          "CATEGORY_TYPE": [
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "CATEGORY_TYPE_NAME": "DND"
              },
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION": [
                {
                  "@attributes": {
                    "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "L1",
                    "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "11"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "@attributes": {
                    "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "L2",
                    "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "22"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "@attributes": {
                    "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "L3",
                    "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "33"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "@attributes": {
                    "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "L4",
                    "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "44"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "CATEGORY_TYPE_NAME": "MNN"
              },
              "CATEGORY_LOCATION": [
                {
                  "@attributes": {
                    "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Loc33",
                    "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "8"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "@attributes": {
                    "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Loc333",
                    "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "7"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "@attributes": {
                    "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Loc33333",
                    "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "6"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "@attributes": {
                    "CATEGORY_LOCATION_NAME": "Loc333333",
                    "PROPOSED_LEVEL": "5"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
var result = obj["ROOT"]["CATEGORY_AREA_LIST"]["CATEGORY_AREA"].find(current=>{
    if(current["@attributes"]["CATEGORY_AREA_NAME"] == "General")
        return current;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked

var jsArray = JSON.parse(jsonObj);

var result = jsArray["ROOT"]["CATEGORY_AREA_LIST"]["CATEGORY_AREA"].find(current=>{
  if(current["@attributes"]["CATEGORY_AREA_NAME"] == "General")
   return current;
 });

Answer (score 0):

Replace "data" with the reference to your JSON and this will do it:

```
data.ROOT.CATEGORY_AREA_LIST.CATEGORY_AREA.forEach(i => {
    if (i["@attributes"].CATEGORY_AREA_NAME === "General") {
        console.log(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You convert that json to js object first: `var data = JSON.parse(<json string>)`

Then filter:

```
var result = data["ROOT"]["CATEGORY_AREA_LIST"]["CATEGORY_AREA"].filter(function(area) {
  return (area["@attributes"]["CATEGORY_AREA_NAME"] === "General")
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!